# jquery nav bar slidetoggle issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm fairly new to jquery and so far i have got my code to toggle and slide a html menu. heres my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li').each(function(){
$('li.menuheader').hover(function(){
    $('ul.submenu').slideToggle('slow', function(){})
});
}); 

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>


    <li class="menuheader">test1
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
        <li>item 4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>


    <li class="menuheader">test2
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
        <li>item 4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>


    <li class="menuheader">test3
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
        <li>item 4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>


  </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

my jquery dropdowns every menu everytime the mouse hovers over a menuheader. I need to seperate these out without using div id's and making seperate jquery functions. Can anyone help me with how to do this?

Comment: What do you need to do exactly?It's not clear to me

Comment: @heavymetalkid because using id's would mean i would need seperate functions for each element..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for (n need to use slideToggle i think):

```
$('ul.submenu').hide();
$('li').each(function() {
    $('li.menuheader').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('ul.submenu').show('slow')
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('ul.submenu').hide('slow')
    });
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/DRjPF/

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows all `ul.submenu` because they all match the selector. Use `$(this).find('ul.submenu')` to find the appropriate ones for each `li`.

Secondly, for each `li` you bind a `hover` handler for each `li.menuheader`. That's unnecessary.

Also, `hover` triggers at mouseenter and mouseout. `mouseenter` should suffice,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li.menuheader').mouseenter(function() {
        $('ul.submenu').not(this).slideUp('slow'); // hide all
        $(this).find('ul.submenu').slideDown('slow'); // 
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zRvLt/

Answer (score 0):

`$('li.menuheader')` ==> this will select all the `menuheaders`. Filter them with `this`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li').each(function(){
        $(this).('menuheader').hover(function(){
            $(this).children('ul.submenu').slideToggle('slow', function(){
                ....
            })
        });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: this looks about right, but i've tried it and it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Pink, I think @Nicola Peluchetti came up with the workable solution for that. +1 for him.